# Cómo convertir en JavaScript un array de cadenas de texto con sintaxis JSON a un array de objetos

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Estoy realizando un multiselect, el cual al seleccionar un valor se va al js al método asignarEmpleado. Lo que está sucediendo es que al enviar los datos están llegando al js como un array de cadenas de texto (cada elemento del array contiene sintaxis JSON) y lo deseado es un array de objetos. El código del multiselect es el siguiente:

```
<multiselect @input="asignarEmpleado"
                                 @Open="limpiarMensajeErrorMultiselect"
                                 :clear-on-select="false"
                                 :close-on-select="false"
                                 :disabled="form.camposAtributos.empleados.disabled"
                                 :multiple="true"
                                 :options="comboEmpleados"
                                 :show-labels="false"
                                 clase="form-control form-control-sm"
                                 id="empleados"
                                 label="nombre"
                                 placeholder="Seleccione..."
                                 ref="empleados"
                                 track-by="nombre"
                                 v-model="$v.form.campos.empleados.$model"></multiselect>
```

Al enviar los datos al js, al método asignarEmpleado, me está enviando los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
empleados: ['{"id":1,"idAnaProy":1,"horas":1}']
```

Como podría hacer para que me lo envíe así:

```
empleados: [{id:1, idAnaProy:1, horas:1}]
```

Comment: Has usado los tags `javascript` y `html`, pero juraría que eso que veo ahí es `vue`... usar los tags apropiados ayuda mucho a encontrar respuesta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voy a suponer que lo que deseas es convertir un arreglo de "objetos" (están en forma de texto) a un arreglo de objetos. Y, como dice el título de la pregunta, en JavaScript, o sea, sin importar si usas Vue u otro framework o biblioteca.

Por ejemplo:

```
var empleados = ['{"id":1,"idAnaProy":1,"horas":1}', '{"id":2,"idAnaProy":2,"horas":3}'];
```

Entonces una forma de hacerlo puede ser la siguiente:

```
var arrObj = empleados.map(txtObj => JSON.parse(txtObj));
```

Y puedes acceder, por ejemplo, al id del primer empleado de la siguiente forma:

```
arrObj[0].id
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar la siguiente función

```
Object.assign({}, ['a','b','c']); // {0:"a", 1:"b", 2:"c"}
```

Quiza pueda ayudarte
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object